# How do I get back to the main site with this new format?

Tags: support

I worked out how to get to meta by clicking on the help tab. Where is the link back to the main site?

[image: tab]

Comment: Hmm... I think a few people have been caught by the changes. MSO has been featuring it for a few weeks though and I think I like it.

Answer (score 4):

It's ok I worked it out when from my screen shot.

[image]

*Utter brainiac brilliance surely! hahaha (aka thick as two planks over here)*

Comment: You'll notice there is also a link to get to meta there as well!